# What is the best way to execute task five seconds after method call in Java

Tags: java, timer

When I call the following method, I want the code nested inside of it to execute after five seconds. I know there are several ways to do this but I want to know the best and most efficient way to accomplish this in java?

```
public void callMe() {
  System.out.println("This is a message!");
}
```

Thanks,
Faraaz

Comment: What have you tried?  Googling Java timer?  Thread?

Comment: create a Thread which sleeps 5 seconds and executes

Comment: Yeah, I've tried various methods but I want to know the most efficient and lightest method,

Comment: define *best way* ?

Comment: The fastest and most efficient way to make a timer. I've seens lots of different ways but I want to know the best way.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can accomplish that by using timer.schedule()

Code:

```
 public static void callMe() {
 new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             System.out.println("This is a message!");
        }
    }, 
    5000 
 );
```

Comment: but is this the *best way*?

Comment: Yes, the best way for your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

    for (int i = 0;
         i < importantInfo.length;
         i++) {
        //Pause for 4 seconds
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        //Print a message
        System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
    }
}
}
}
```

For more information You can also visit the following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html